# How to test wrapped component with enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My React components is wrapped with differents HOCs (i18next, graphql etc...), unfortunately I can't test my wrappedComponents with enzyme.

What is your best practice to test your wrappedComponents?

I do not wish to export wrapped and unwrapped components version, I would like to only export wrapped component for my application logic and be able to test unwrapped component inside my wrapped component.

Thanks for reading me!

Comment: Most well-designed HOCs expose original components, as one of the answers show. This is a good practice to export and test unwrapped components in case they don't expose them.

Comment: I think it depends on how you organize your HoCs. If you tend to use only one, i.e. `connect` or `graphql`, then exposing wrapped component as static member may be sufficient. However, if you use libraries like `recompose`, which prefer composition of multiple smaller HoCs then you could end up with `HoC.WrappedComponent.WrappedComponent.WrappedComponent`, etc. In this case I think there's nothing wrong with exporting "base" component as well.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to favour the same approach that Redux takes with `connect`, and make the actual component available as a static on the exported component.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => ( ... );

const ConnectedComponent = usingMyHoc(...)(MyComponent) ;
ConnectedComponent.WrappedComponent = MyComponent;

export default ConnectedComponent;
```

Comment: After several tests, your answer seems the best because it cover the case when your component is wrapped by multiple HoC. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I agree that exporting unwrapped components feels unnatural -- you want to test your components exactly how they are used in production.

My preferred method is creating a wrapped render function to use in testing:

```
function renderWithProviders(componentTree, options = {}) {
    const {initialState} = options;
    const store = initializeStore(initialState);
    return {
        ...render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SnackbarProvider>{componentTree}</SnackbarProvider>
    </Provider>
    )};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This also covers multiple HOCs.